# Style post archive blog preview based on category

Tags: categories

0
down vote
favorite
I have a page showing your typical series of small post teasers - images, excerpt etc which advertise properties for lease.

I would like to have the ability to add a 'new' or 'featured' icon based on its corresponding 'new' or 'featured' category or tag - either will do.

I have added these categories but they do not appear in the code when output and so I cannot target them.

How would I be able to perform the action:

If a post thumbnail has category of 'new' add the class 'new' so I can then target and style - repeating for each category.

I found this below which I think is similar but does not work

There will be multiple categories displaying on the archive page, but I want to style only the previews that have a certain category - I do not want to style the individual post page.

Unfortunately my php skills are limited

Thanks

```
$post = $wp_query->post;

if ( in_category('new', $post->ID) ) { ?>
    <body <?php body_class('new'); ?>> 
<?php
} 

elseif ( in_category('featured', $post->ID) ) { ?>
    <body <?php body_class('featured'); ?>> 
<?php
} 

else { ?>
    <body <?php body_class('class-name-generic'); ?>>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that should go to the [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) - you want this class per post, not for the whole `<body>`, right? Roughly `archive.php` (or `index.php`, or `category-*.php`) should look like this:

```php
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    $add_class = array();
    if (in_category('new')) { // inside the loop, don't need $post->ID
        $add_class[] = 'new';
    if (in_category('featured'))
        $add_class[] = 'featured'; // and so on
    ?>
    <article <?php post_class($add_class); ?>>
    <?php // ...
}
```

Or, depending on the theme, in `content.php` or some version thereof.
See docs for [post_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this to work. I pasted it in all the suggested php templates I have discovered that the php template outputting the post grid is a visual composer php file, I tried in there too but not such luck.

Comment: But please don't paste it verbatim, this is just a guideline! You could try and show the relevant code here, but the Visual Composers and Pagebuilders I've seen can have a complex, convoluted and sometimes messy code...